# calculate select option value on table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, each

I think I got problem with js and html (bootstrap),
I got these snippet from bootsnip and try to modified it for need of my job.
but on the third lines, sorry for typo or bad using english.

the bootsnip here (my modification) : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/o8r0G

```js
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#addr'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><select class='form-control' name='slct"+i+"' placeholder='Select'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select></td>");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
      if(i>1){
   $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
   i--;
   }
  });

});

$('.buttonx').click(function() {
    var total = 0;

    $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(index) { 

        var price = parseInt($(this).find('.optx sltx option value').text()); 
        var quantity = parseInt($(this).find('.optx sltx option').val()); 
        var value = $(this).find('.value');
        var subTotal = price * quantity;

        value.text(subTotal);
        value.text(price);
        total = total + subTotal;
        testotal = price;

    });

    $('.totality').text('Total : '+testotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12 column">
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
     <tr >
      <th class="text-center">
       #
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Value1
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Value2
      </th>
      <th class="text-center">
       Select
      </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr id='addr0'>
      <td>
      1
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='va10'  placeholder='Val1' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name='va20' placeholder='Val2' class="form-control"/>
      </td>
      <td class="optx">
      <select class="form-control sltx" name="slct0" placeholder="Select"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
      </td>
     </tr>
                    <tr id='addr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th><a id="buttonx" class="btn btn-default btn-danger pull-right">Calculate</a></th>
                        <th id="totality" style="vertical-align: middle;">Total : </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create the total from the table but I can't load the value from table with js, maybe I got wrong on the script which I got from other answer on stack. Reference is here : [getting values from a html table via javascript/jquery and doing a calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240779/getting-values-from-a-html-table-via-javascript-jquery-and-doing-a-calculation)

I want to ask, how can I got the calculation from select option on table, alternatively from input textbox and without I push the button (real time calculation).

Thanks before.

Comment: what's the total formula?is it `value1 + value2 + select value`?

Comment: `value1` | `value2` | `value1 + value2 + select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as per my understand-ability, you need a real time calculator, which calculate value as user entering and leave any textbox or change the select without using the calculate button.

In your code there are some error, I have built and change some of your function to implement the real time calculator. calculation formula is different because I am not able to understand how you are going to calculate. I am implementing it using the **class selector** of the element and fetching the value with the use of this.

Here is the updated code which is using both, on click button and also real time calculator.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 column">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th class="text-center">
                            #
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Value1
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Value2
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-center">
                            Select
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id='addr0'>
                        <td>
                        1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='va10'  placeholder='Val1' class="form-control va10"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name='va20' placeholder='Val2' class="form-control va20"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="optx">
                        <select class="form-control sltx slct0" name="slct0" placeholder="Select"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th><a id="buttonx" class="btn btn-default btn-danger pull-right">Calculate</a></th>
                        <th id="totality" style="vertical-align: middle;">Total : </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default">Delete Row</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#tab_logic').append("<tr id='addr"+i+"'><td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='name'"+i+" type='text' class='form-control va10' placeholder='Name' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='mail'"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Mail'  class='va20 form-control input-md'></td><td><select class='form-control slct0' name='slct'"+i+" placeholder='Select'><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option></select></td></tr");


      i++; 
  });
     $("#delete_row").click(function(){
         if(i>1){
         $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
         i--;
         }
     });

});

function calculator(){
var total = 0;

    $('#tab_logic tbody tr').each(function(index) { 

        var val1 = $(this).find('.va10').val().length==0?0:parseInt($(this).find('.va10').val()); 
        var val2 = $(this).find('.va20').val().length==0?0:parseInt($(this).find('.va20').val()); 
        var select = $(this).find('.slct0').val().length==0?0:parseInt($(this).find('.slct0').val());
        var subTotal = (val1 + val2)*select;
        total+=subTotal;    

    });    
    $('#totality').text(total);
}
$('#tab_logic').on('blur change','.va10,.va20,.slct0',function(){
calculator()
})
$('#buttonx').click(function() {
    calculator();
});


</script>
```